# The mystery of WiFi no one could solve. Sherlock of networking can you solve this issue?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, internet

**Driver**: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235

**Laptop**: NP550P5C-S05IN

**Operating System**: Win-10

**Log in** : Cyberoam

I have been using this laptop for quite some time now and had no problem at all till some time back. I had to format my laptop and re-install Windows-10 due to malware. I was using my college's WiFi earlier too and there was no problem then.

But after re-installing windows again my WiFi don't work properly any more. That is: it continuously get connected and disconnected to WiFi. As I am in college so we have our accounts to log-in to access the internet, we use Cyberoam here. What happen is I will log-in into my Cyberoam account then after using internet for 5-10 minutes it will get disconnected, then I will have to switch WiFi on-off or try refreshing again and again. My laptop works fine with every other network.

I have tried re-allocating the IP address using : netsh int ip reset and all other similar command to rest DNS, IP etc. Also I have tried re-installing windows-10 multiple times, also have re-installed drivers multiple times but no luck. I tried asking the IT department regarding this issue but alas they have no clue, they tried basic network troubleshooting but when does that ever work.

**Process**:

1. I will log in into my Cyberoam account.
2. Will use the internet for few minutes.
3. Then my internet will stop working.Although I am still connected to the WiFi network
4. My cyberoam account would freeze or would get disconnected eventually
5. Then I will either turn my WiFi (in laptop) on and off repeatedly or I will connect and disconnect.
6. After repeating step 5 again and again I will get to Log in into cyberoam again, Then after 5-10 minutes the same thing will repeat

**Wlan report:**

[images of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzggB.jpg)

Also there were three drivers present in Samsung driver kit(I don't know what is difference between them):

1. Bluetooth Driver
2. LAN Driver
3. Wireless Lan driver

Comment: You may want to check the encryption protocol used for connecting. You do connect using WPA2, right ?

Comment: Password is used to connect to the WiFi, so I guess WPA2 is used. But as I have set it to: connect automatically, so I need not to enter the password every time. The Wlan report ( you can check in the link) shows that driver is responsible for disconnection, but I have downloaded the official Intel driver and also updated it.